# For a sufficiently large $a$, are there distinct (mod $a$) integers such that all powers up to the $n$-th are "close" modulo $a$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, congruences

Given $n\in\Bbb N$ is there an $a_n\in\Bbb N$ such that for every $a>a_n$ there are two distinct integers $0<b<c<a$ such that $b^i\bmod a,c^i\bmod a\in(\sqrt a,\sqrt a\log a)$ for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$?

If so what is minimum such $a$?

Comment: Could you prove this for $n=2$? Is it true that if $m$ is large enough, then there are at least two (distinct) elements $b\in{\mathbb Z}_m$
such that both $b$ and $b^2$ belong to $(\sqrt m,\sqrt m\log m)\pmod m$? Have you tried using exponential sums to prove this?

Comment: @Seva I am not familiar with exp sums.

Comment: Ok, still, how about $n=2$?

Comment: @Seva it is unclear even there.

Comment: @Seva how would you use exp sums here?

Comment: I think $n=2$ is fine, just take $b:=[\sqrt{a}]+1$ and $c:=[\sqrt{a}]+2$.

Comment: BTW I find this question quite interesting. I am surprised by the lack of upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a heuristic, but perhaps it can be made rigorous with some
effort (using Weil's bound etc).

I write $m$ instead of your $a$. Let $I:=(\sqrt m,\sqrt m\log m)\pmod m$. You
want to show that there are at least two distinct values of $b\in{\mathbb
Z}_m$ such that $b,\dotsc,b^n\in I$. The number of such $b$ is
  $$ \frac1{m^n} \sum_{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\in I} \sum_{u_1,\dotsc,u_n\in{\mathbb Z}_m}
      \sum_{b\in{\mathbb Z}_m} e^{ \frac{(b-x_1)u_1+\dotsb+(b^n-x_n)u_n}{m} }. $$
The main term obtained for $u_1=\dotsb=u_n=0$ is $|I|^n/m^{n-1}$, which is of
the order of magnitude $m^{1-n/2}(\log m)^n$. This is a small number for
$n\ge 3$ and $m$ large, and it is thus plausible to expect that in this case you cannot (in general) find even one single $b\in{\mathbb Z}_m$ with the property in question.

Comment: I was thinking of similar conclusion on the way here in my car. I thought it is impossible for $n\geq 3$. I did not know this exp sum trick. So if this main term is small then it is definitely impossible to have such pairs of b or just heuristically? Can we make this definite? Also could you show why main term is as you calculated?

Comment: @Turbo: calculating the main term is a triviality, just plug in $u_1=\dotsb =u_n=0$. The non-trivial thing is to estimate the remainder term, which is the rest of the sum. If it turns out to be smaller in absolute value than the main term, then yes, it is definitely impossible to find $b$ as you want.

Comment: here in this problem is remainder computation hard? is this exp sum kind of general trick at some 'non-trivial' things?

Comment: also conversely what you would have expected if say up to $n=40$ we could 'definitely' expect such pairs?

Comment: @Turbo: one cannot say whether it is hard without actually trying, for which unfortunately I don't have time now. Maybe, it is easy. Anyway, this is not just a "trick"; dating back to Gauss, exponential / character sums form is a rich area with many famous mathematicians involved and lots of top-rate research done on it. And, I don't understand your question starting with "also conversely".

Comment: thank you how about converse query 'what you would have expected if say up to $n=40$ we could 'definitely' expect such pairs?'?

Comment: @Turbo: not sure I've got your last question right, but in case I have: you would know that at least two values of $b$ exist if you can show that the absolute value of the remainder term is does not exceed the main term less $2$.

Comment: You mentioned that if $n\geq3$ then $m^{1-\frac n2}(\log m)^n\ll1$ and it is unlikely we will have even one $b$ such that $b,b^2$ and $b^3$ are bounded. My query is that 'supposing we had $m^{1-\frac n{40}}(\log m)^n$ instead would it 'definitely' be true that we will have pairs such that $a,a^2,\dots,a^{40},b,b^2,\dots,b^{40}$ are all bounded? Or should we also have to know that the remainder term be at most $O(m^{1-\frac n{40-\epsilon}}(\log m)^n)$ to be certain such $40$ length pairs exist?'?